# Slim php container setup

Tags: php, slim

I am fairly new to slim php, i want to learn about containers but with not much luck, i tried so hard to get it done but still i get nothing.

```
--api
   --src
     --Controllers
       --HomeController.php
     --public
       --.htaccess
       --index.php
  .htaccess
```

index.php

```
use DI\Container;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use api\Controllers\HomeController;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$container = new Container();

AppFactory::setContainer($container);
$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->setBasePath('/api');

$container->set('HomeController', function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    $view = $container->get('view');
    
    return new HomeController($view);
});


$app->get('/', \HomeController::class . ':home');

$app->run();
```

HomeController.php

```
namespace api\Controllers;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;


class HomeController
{
   private $container;

   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
   {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

   public function home(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, array $args): ResponseInterface
   {
        $response->getBody()->write('hello');
        return $response;
   }

}
```

i tried every youtube video tutorial, read every documentation. with no understanding what so ever, i just need a basic container to work so i can understand it in person and tweak with it, thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: You forgot to explain the problem

Comment: The container definition may be a fully qualified class name. Try `$container->set(\api\ControllersHomeController::class,` ...` instead. 
2. Make sure to use the correct namespace: `$app->get('/', \api\Controllers\HomeController::class . ':home');`
3. Make sure that composer.json is configured correctly.
Also note that PHI-DI supports autowiring.
Try this tutorial: https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get things going, I suggest you these steps:

1. Create a `settings.php` file at the root of your project.
   Something like:

```php
<?php

return [
    'settings' => [
        'slim' => [
            'displayErrorDetails' => true,
            'logErrors' => true,
            'logErrorDetails' => true,
        ],
    ],
    // The rest of your container settings go here
];
```

2. Create a `bootstrap.php` file at the root of your project that contains the app container and you can configure that here. An example would be something like:

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$container = new Container(require __DIR__ . '/settings.php');
```

And you can add more singletons to your container:

```php
$container->set(DefaultController::class, function (Container $c) {
    return new DefaultController($c->get(EntityManager::class));
});
```

So that you can use your `EntityManager` in your controllers. Remember that you have to set that and add it to your container as well. With whatever configurations that you want.

3. Now you can create an `index.php` file in the `public` folder, and create your app:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';

AppFactory::setContainer($container);

$app = AppFactory::create();
```

4. Note that you have to configure your namespaced autoload in your `composer.json` like this:

```json
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Slim\\": "Slim",
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Test\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    ...
```

5. Create your controllers and be careful with the namespaces that you use. They are a little tricky.